# MySQL server has gone away SELECT GET_LOCK. in Codeigniter 4

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

## I am getting the following error

This is what I get in the LOG file, I think this query is consuming my server's CPU resources

```
ERROR - 2023-02-27 19:00:58 --> mysqli_sql_exception: MySQL server has gone away in /system/Database/MySQLi/Connection.php:292
Stack trace:
#0 /system/Database/MySQLi/Connection.php(292): mysqli->query('SELECT GET_LOCK...', 0)
#1 /system/Database/BaseConnection.php(666): CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Connection->execute('SELECT GET_LOCK...')
#2 /system/Database/BaseConnection.php(593): CodeIgniter\Database\BaseConnection->simpleQuery('SELECT GET_LOCK...')
#3 /system/Session/Handlers/Database/MySQLiHandler.php(27): CodeIgniter\Database\BaseConnection->query('SELECT GET_LOCK...')
#4 /system/Session/Handlers/DatabaseHandler.php(108): CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\Database\MySQLiHandler->lockSession('72d3fea040bf9e0...')
#5 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\DatabaseHandler->read('72d3fea040bf9e0...')
#6 /system/Session/Session.php(912): session_start()
#7 /system/Session/Session.php(234): CodeIgniter\Session\Session->startSession()
#8 /system/Config/Services.php(665): CodeIgniter\Session\Session->start()
#9 /system/Config/BaseService.php(253): CodeIgniter\Config\Services::session(Object(Config\App), false)
#10 /system/Config/BaseService.php(194): CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::__callStatic('session', Array)
#11 /system/Config/Services.php(637): CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::getSharedInstance('session', NULL)
#12 /system/Config/BaseService.php(253): CodeIgniter\Config\Services::session()
#13 /app/Config/Globals.php(28): CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::__callStatic('session', Array)
#14 /app/Config/Globals.php(111): Config\Globals::setGlobals()
#15 /system/Autoloader/Autoloader.php(282): include_once('...')
#16 /system/Autoloader/Autoloader.php(259): CodeIgniter\Autoloader\Autoloader->includeFile('...')
#17 /system/Autoloader/Autoloader.php(237): CodeIgniter\Autoloader\Autoloader->loadInNamespace('Config\\Globals')
#18 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Autoloader\Autoloader->loadClass('Config\\Globals')
#19 /app/Config/Routes.php(7): spl_autoload_call('Config\\Globals')
#20 /system/CodeIgniter.php(789): require('...')
#21 /system/CodeIgniter.php(430): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->tryToRouteIt(Object(CodeIgniter\Router\RouteCollection))
#22 /system/CodeIgniter.php(351): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->handleRequest(NULL, Object(Config\Cache), false)
#23 /index.php(78): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->run()
#24 {main}
CRITICAL - 2023-02-27 19:00:58 --> Call to a member function getRow() on bool
in /Session/Handlers/Database/MySQLiHandler.php on line 27.
 1 /Session/Handlers/DatabaseHandler.php(108): CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\Database\MySQLiHandler->lockSession('72d3fea040bf9e05c8c6394b11317110e8864aef')
 2 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\DatabaseHandler->read('72d3fea040bf9e05c8c6394b11317110e8864aef')
 3 /Session/Session.php(912): session_start()
 4 /Session/Session.php(234): CodeIgniter\Session\Session->startSession()
 5 /Config/Services.php(665): CodeIgniter\Session\Session->start()
 6 /Config/BaseService.php(253): CodeIgniter\Config\Services::session(Object(Config\App), false)
 7 /Config/BaseService.php(194): CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::__callStatic('session', [...])
 8 /Config/Services.php(637): CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::getSharedInstance('session', null)
 9 /Config/BaseService.php(253): CodeIgniter\Config\Services::session()
10 /Config/Globals.php(28): CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::__callStatic('session', [])
11 /Config/Globals.php(111): Config\Globals::setGlobals()
12 /Autoloader/Autoloader.php(282): include_once('/Config/Globals.php')
13 /Autoloader/Autoloader.php(259): CodeIgniter\Autoloader\Autoloader->includeFile('/Config/Globals.php')
14 /Autoloader/Autoloader.php(237): CodeIgniter\Autoloader\Autoloader->loadInNamespace('Config\\Globals')
15 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Autoloader\Autoloader->loadClass('Config\\Globals')
16 /Config/Routes.php(7): spl_autoload_call('Config\\Globals')
17 /CodeIgniter.php(789): require('/Config/Routes.php')
18 /CodeIgniter.php(430): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->tryToRouteIt(Object(CodeIgniter\Router\RouteCollection))
19 /CodeIgniter.php(351): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->handleRequest(null, Object(Config\Cache), false)
20 /index.php(78): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->run()
```

## These are the queries

```
        $arg = md5($sessionID . ($this->matchIP ? '_' . $this->ipAddress : ''));
        if ($this->db->query("SELECT GET_LOCK('{$arg}', 600) AS ci_session_lock")->getRow()->ci_session_lock) {
            $this->lock = $arg;

            return true;
        }

        return $this->fail();

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

     if (! $this->lock) {
            return true;
        }

        if ($this->db->query("SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('{$this->lock}') AS ci_session_lock")->getRow()->ci_session_lock) {
            $this->lock = false;

            return true;
        }

        return $this->fail();
```

Could someone help me I have tried everything and I cannot solve the error

I don't understand what's wrong, I've already tried everything

Comment: In your case, the error seems to be caused by a `SELECT GET_LOCK` query that is taking up too much CPU resources.

Comment: Is there any way to minimize resource consumption with the query?

Comment: Lots of things to see. Try increase the value of the "wait_timeout" and "interactive_timeout" parameters in your MySQL configuration file. These parameters control how long the server waits for a connection to be active before closing it.

Comment: "gone away" means your MySQL server process crashed. Look at your system logs to find out why it crashed.

Comment: The record is the one I posted above

Comment: @kampit  I use a semi-dedicated server, I do not have access to modify this information. I will die trying to optimize the web... mmmm

Comment: Please don't die. We still have time to look forward to beautiful days. Contact your hoster to get the logs.

Comment: We need more information to be able to assist you, as your question does not give nay context. Calling `GET_LOCK()` with a timeout of 10 minutes is a really bad idea. Your problem is occurring because the lock is already held so it is timing out. You can use `SELECT * FROM performance_schema.metadata_locks WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'USER LEVEL LOCK';` to see what locks are already held.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.